# Controlling image output size ACF repeater

Tags: php, images

I am using ACF repeater and am not able to control the output size incorporating Wordpress theme support custom image sizes

```
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_image_size('large', 700, '', true); 
    add_image_size('medium', 250, '', true); 
    add_image_size('small', 120, '', true); 
    add_image_size('custom-size', 700, 200, true);
```

I am currently using image url for the selection in ACF repeater field because I can't get the image to display using ID or Object. I have spent hours reading articles and questions relating to the subject and can't find an answer that is relevant to my code. This is my most recent attempt.

```
 <?php foreach(get_field('landing_slideshow') as $landing_slideshow) { ?>
     <div class="landing-photo clear" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $landing_slideshow['landing_slide']['sizes']['medium']; ?>');">
     </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

I am simply wanting to specify image output size using 'large', 'custom-size' etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always set ACF to return "ID" (not object or URL) - that way ACF doesn't get involved (& potentionally populate an object with vast amounts of data I don't need) and I can do as I wish:

```
<?php

$landing_slideshows = get_field( 'landing_slideshow' );

// var_dump( $landing_slideshows );

foreach( $landing_slideshows as $landing_slideshow ) : ?>

    <div class="landing-photo clear"<?php

        $image_id = $landing_slideshow['landing_slide'];
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'large' );

        // Only print style bg if image valid & exists, unlikely but good practice
        if ( $src ) {
            // $src is an array with 3 items: URL, width, height
            printf( ' style="background-image: url(%s);"', $src[0] );
        }

    ?>><?php

        // var_dump( $image_id );
        // var_dump( $src );

    ?></div>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: + 1 for the creativity and effort, but that didn't work. I tried it with and with out your code chunk wrapped in  <?php foreach(get_field('landing_slideshow') as $landing_slideshow) { ?><?php }?>

Comment: Can you help me help you - can you elaborate on "didn't work"? Did you get any errors? What happens if you `var_dump` some of the variables? And make sure that you have [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: Your code did not cause any errors, but no image was rendered. I var dumped $image_id $src $landing_slideshow and those were empty. If I was in fact implementing that correctly. I did switch to id in the ACF image category as well. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Just for clarity I have updated my answer with the full snippet. Uncomment the debug lines if it still isn't working.